# What could this little plant be?

Tags: identification, tomatoes, seedlings, strawberries, squash

I noticed this tiny plant growing in the pots where a tomato and a squash are growing. A few days ago I found this same plant growing in a pot where I'm growing lettuce. This makes me doubt if the strawberry plants I'm attempting to grow are truly strawberries, since they were taking so long to germinate that I thought they wouldn't germinate at all and left them forgotten in my patio for weeks, until I decided I needed those pots for other seeds so I went to pick them up and found little seedlings growing. I thought that finally the strawberry seeds germinated, but now I'm not so sure since the seedlings look awfully similar to those growing in my other pots.
So what could they be? And is the little plant growing in the clear pot really a strawberry seedling? I'm new to gardening so honestly have no idea and even though I googled to see what strawberry seedlings are supposed to look like, I'm still not sure.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first one is tomato, the second one squash. It could also be melon or pumpkin, but when you say you had squash there this is it.

The last one I don't know for sure, it could be strawberry but you'll have to wait for the real leaves to come out to know for sure.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your... help. Very helpful indeed...